# I need a best way to transform json response in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api, multiprocessing

I'm trying to get a dataframe from a api response.
For optimization I run parallels threads, but the time is really high.
An code example:

```
def parall_func(tuple):
   output = pd.DataFrame()
   list_caracts = list(map(str,tuple[2]))
   item = [(tuple[1])]
   q = len(list_caracts)
   
   headers = {
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
   }
   raw_data = json.dumps(
        {"item": item,"list_caracts": list_caracts, "sizePage":q, "numberPage":1}
    )
   try:
      url = "https://thisisaurl.com/rep/store"
      response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,data=raw_data)
      resp_to_json = json.loads(response.text)

      for i in resp_to_json['tag']:

            output = output.append([i])
            
    except:
        print("Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise
    return output

pool = Threads(cpu_count())
df_parall=list(pool.imap(parall_func, df_queries.itertuples(name=None)))
pool.close()
Final=pd.concat(df_parall, ignore_index=True)
```

can you help me to correct or suggest another logic or structure different to pandas

the final response has at about 3 millions of records

After I can get the structure i need do some of calcs and then connect to a db with pyodbc to save the data

Answer (score 0):

The two things I would try are:

1. Create a `requests.Session` instance and use that to issue your GET requests. According to the documentation for this:

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance, and will use urllib3’s connection pooling. So if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase (see HTTP persistent connection).

2. Since you are using multithreading, limiting yourself to only a number of threads equal to the number of cores you have will result in under performance. Try creating 500 threads. The only issue becomes whether the website will not complain that too many requests per second are being made.

By the way, you source had an indentation error. I have supplied missing import statements as I suppose they should be and I have renamed argument *tuple* to *tpl* since `tuple` is a built-in type and you should not redefine built-in types without a good reason.

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Threads
from requests import Session
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd
import sys


def parall_func(session, tpl):
    output = pd.DataFrame()
    list_caracts = list(map(str,tpl[2]))
    item = [(tpl[1])]
    q = len(list_caracts)
   
    raw_data = json.dumps(
        {"item": item,"list_caracts": list_caracts, "sizePage":q, "numberPage":1}
    )
    try:
        url = "https://thisisaurl.com/rep/store"
        response = session.get(url, data=raw_data)
        resp_to_json = json.loads(response.text)

        for i in resp_to_json['tag']:
            output = output.append([i])

    except:
        print("Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise
    return output

with Session() as session:
    headers = {
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    }
    session.headers = headers
    pool = Threads(500)
    df_parall=list(pool.imap(partial(parall_func, session), df_queries.itertuples(name=None)))
    pool.close()
    Final=pd.concat(df_parall, ignore_index=True)
```

**Update**

One additional thing you can try is to replace creating variable `output` by doing multiple `append` operations with a single `concat`:

```py
def parall_func(session, tpl):
    list_caracts = list(map(str,tpl[2]))
    item = [(tpl[1])]
    q = len(list_caracts)
   
    raw_data = json.dumps(
        {"item": item,"list_caracts": list_caracts, "sizePage":q, "numberPage":1}
    )
    try:
        url = "https://thisisaurl.com/rep/store"
        response = session.get(url, data=raw_data)
        resp_to_json = json.loads(response.text)

        dataframes = [pd.DataFrame([i]) for i in resp_to_json['tag']]
        output = pd.concat(dataframes)

    except:
        print("Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise
    return output
```

If the above doesn't improve performance, one last thing to try is to have the creation of the dataframes done using multiprocessing:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Threads, Pool as MultiProcessingPool
from requests import Session
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd
import sys


def create_data_frames(response):
    resp_to_json = json.loads(response.text)

    dataframes = [pd.DataFrame([i]) for i in resp_to_json['tag']]
    # Perhaps you might want to specify ignore_index=True on the following:
    output = pd.concat(dataframes)
    return output
                      
def parall_func(session, multiprocessing_pool, tpl):
    list_caracts = list(map(str,tpl[2]))
    item = [(tpl[1])]
    q = len(list_caracts)
   
    raw_data = json.dumps(
        {"item": item,"list_caracts": list_caracts, "sizePage":q, "numberPage":1}
    )
    try:
        url = "https://thisisaurl.com/rep/store"
        response = session.get(url, data=raw_data)
        output = multiprocessing_pool.apply(create_data_frames, args=(response,))

    except:
        print("Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise
    return output

with Session() as session:
    headers = {
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    }
    session.headers = headers
    multiprocessing_pool = MultiProcessingPool()
    pool = Threads(500)
    df_parall=list(pool.imap(partial(parall_func, session, multiprocessing_pool), df_queries.itertuples(name=None)))
    multiprocessing_pool.close()   
    multiprocessing_pool.join()   
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    Final=pd.concat(df_parall, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. it work, but do not get better the previous execution time.

Comment: I have updated the answer with two more things to try if the first doesn't help.